# How solve instance problem with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new learner of Symfony 4 and I'm looking for help. I've an Entity named "Player" and I want to generate a random confirmation number.

For now, I'm using a variable **$confirmNbr** and I save the $confirm in my database with **$participant->setConfirmationNumber($confirmNbr);**.

What I want it's create a function **generateRandomNumber()** in my Entity Player.php like this :

```
public function generateConfirmationNumber() : self 
{

    $this->confirmationNumber = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',6)),0,5);

    return $this;
}
```

This is my Controller file

```
   /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function new(Player $player, EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request)
    {
        $participant = $this->playerrepo->findAll();

        $form = $this->createForm(PlayerFormType::class);

        $randomNbr = $player->generateConfirmationNumber();



        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $participant = new Player;
            $participant->setName($data['name']);
            $participant->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
            $participant->setEmail($data['email']);
            $participant->setConfirmationNumber($confirmNbr);
            $participant->setRegisterAt(new \DateTime);

            $em->persist($player);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Player added!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('app/subscribe.html.twig', [
            'playerForm' => $form->createView(),
            'player'=>$player,
        ]);
    }
```

And this is my error message :

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request
>   information for parameter "player".

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is expecting an instance of the `Player` object - where should it come from? Doctrine is trying to guess it and get it from the URL, but it cannot. Your method is for creating new players - why do you need an instance of a player? Just remove that parameter from the method signature, i.e. change it to:

`public function new(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request)`

Comment: But if I want to call a function from my Entity ( function that I created ), how can I do then ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You can just create a Player like you do in your if,  `$participant = new Player();`, right ? You can create it at the start of your method if you want. You should also pass the instance to `createForm` so the `handleRequest()` will populate it as sonne as there parameter matching your Entity fields, no need to set manually your data.

Comment: @Etshy Thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea why it give me the message **Call to a member function generateConfirmationNumber() on array** ? I understand it's not possible to call a function on the array but if that's work with getter and setter, why not with a function that I made ?

Comment: on your `$data` variable you mean ? no need for it, do like this : `$form = $this->createForm(PlayerFormType::class, $participant );` and `$participant` will have the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I've modified my set function and deleted my function that I've added. Everything works!